# .NET MAUI open system settings

Tags: .net, maui

Can someone tell me how using .NET MAUI I can force the system to open system settings, or better system settings > myApp > permissions ? I am trying to write code which redirect user to settings after not allow app to use camera.

Both Android and iOS

I tried looking for something connected to Intent

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 11):

In the APIs that are formerly known as Essentials, there is the `AppInfo` which allows you to open the settings page for your app.

You can use it as `AppInfo.Current.ShowSettingsUI();`

Read more about this in the Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/app-information?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios#display-app-settings

Comment: Don't forget to mark as an answer if it helped. Glad to be of service!

Comment: AppInfo.Current.ShowSettingsUI();

Comment: Is there a way to open the general settings page, or even a subpage like the time settings?

Comment: for anyone wondering, I found a solution for that:

        var intent = new Intent(Settings.ActionDateSettings);
        var activity = await Platform.WaitForActivityAsync();
        activity.StartActivity(intent);